# user not allowed to connect to wifi

Tags: debian, networking, command-line, wifi

I have a Debian 8 jessie minimal install connected to a wired network. No X server is installed and no GUI.

On this system I log in as unpriviledged user and I notice that the following commands are missing from the autocompletion list: `ifconfig`, `iwconfig`, `wpa_supplicant`, even though they are installed on the system. However I can run `ip a` to get a list of network interfaces.

I would like to know the following:

- is it possible to connect to wifi as an usual user?
- why the usual user is not allowed access to the `ifconfig`, `iwconfig`, `wpa_supplicant` commands ?
- which user group should I be a member of to be able to connect to the wifi network?

Answer (score 3):

It's not that an unprivileged user isn't allowed to use these commands, it's that their location is not by default in a regular user's `PATH`.

On my Jessie box, these commands live under `/sbin` rather than `/bin`; however, my regular user is able to run them with `/sbin/command`.

Comment: An unprivileged user won't be able to change the network configuration with any tool directly, even if she uses their full path (or augments `PATH`) to invoke them. One'll have to go through some policy daemon, like *network-manager* for example.

Comment: thanks for your answer, indeed I do not have /sbin in the user's $PATH. No the question I would ask is why is /sbin not included in the user's $PATH by default?

Comment: @Dasj That's typically what you want. `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` typically contain administrative tools that a regular user typically has no business using anyway. Indeed, as [Ferenc Wágner commented](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347171/user-not-allowed-to-connect-to-wifi/347195?noredirect=1#comment614469_347195), an unprivileged user can't leverage these tools directly to alter network connection status: you need a higher level tool to do it on your behalf.

Comment: @JosephR. thanks for clarification... now you are saying that I need a higher lever tool... which console-only tool would allow an unpriviledged user manage the wifi internet connection? I can not install network-manager as Ferenc suggested because I am in a console environment.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to connect to wifi as an usual user?

The answer is YES

---

> why the usual user is not allowed access to the ifconfig, iwconfig, wpa_supplicant commands ?

Because the usual user is not a part of `netdev` group

> [`netdev`](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemGroups):
>
> Members of this group can manage network interfaces through the network manager and wicd.

---

> which user group should I be a member of to be able to connect to the wifi network?

All member of `netdev` group are allowed to run the network command

You can add the unprivileged user to `netdev` group as follow:

```
adduser user_name_here netdev
```

Reload `dbus` : `/etc/init.d/dbus reload`

**Edit**

Edit your `~/.bashrc`, add the following line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

then run `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: It seems I am already a member of `netdev` group but still can not access those commands directly

Comment: What is the output of `export PATH=$PATH:/sbin && ifconfig` ?

Comment: as expected I get the output of ifconfig which is the list of network interfaces